# CountIfs not working with decimals

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with about 7000 rows of data which I want to analyze using CountIfs. The data consists of decimal numbers such as "0,05234234" (the decimal "point" is a comma due to country settings). My CountIfs code looks like this:

```
    For i = 1 To 6
        lastRow = w3.Worksheets(i).Cells(w3.Worksheets(i).Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For j = 1 To n
            tmpRow = 2
            Set rng = w3.Worksheets(i).Range(w3.Worksheets(i).Cells(2, 1 + j), w3.Worksheets(i).Cells(lastRow, 1 + j))
            Do While w1.Worksheets(i).Cells(tmpRow, 1) <> ""
                If tmpRow = 2 Then
                    above = CDbl(-100) 'first element
                Else
                    above = w1.Worksheets(i).Cells(tmpRow - 1, 1)
                End If
                curr = w1.Worksheets(i).Cells(tmpRow, 1)
                ccount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng, ">" & above, rng, "<=" & curr)
                w1.Worksheets(i).Cells(tmpRow, 1 + j) = ccount
                tmpRow = tmpRow + 1
            Loop
            above = w1.Worksheets(i).Cells(tmpRow - 1, 1)
            w1.Worksheets(i).Cells(tmpRow, 1 + j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, ">" & above)
            tmpRow = tmpRow + 1
        Next j
    Next i
```

The values of "above" and "curr" are evenly spaced like this -2,-1,99,..,0,..,1,99,2.

However, it's not working and it's driving me crazy. The value of "ccount" is 0 for every iteration, except the very last after the loop. For that one, "above" is equal to 2, an integer. It turns out the CountIfs will only work if "above" and "curr" are integers. Why is that happening and how do I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the variable *n*? Using `Option Explicit` at the top of the code will force declaration of variables and help you figure out issues more easily. Since all the code is not pasted, comments in the code would help too :)

Comment: You have avoided showing what the *above* and *curr* variables were declared as. With that scope of data, I would recommend `Dim above as double, curr as double`. Wrapping their value assignment in CDbl couldn't hurt either. e.g. `above = CDbl(w1.Worksheets(i).Cells(tmpRow - 1, 1).Value2)`

Comment: Thanks for the replies! n is an Integer, above and curr are Double. I have tried the forced conversion with CDbl, it didn't do the trick. I'll try Axel's suggestions and get back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the decimal separator is comma due to the locale settings, then implicit conversion of `Double` to `String` and explicit conversion with `CStr` results in a `String` with comma as decimal separator. But this is not correct for `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs`. There a decimal point is needed.

So we have to use `Str` here for conversion. This will ever convert to a `String` with decimal point.

How you can test this behavior:

```
Sub test()

 Dim above As Double

 above = 1.23

 'Excel's decimal separator is comma due to the locale settings!

 s = "<" & above ' "<1,23" - implicit conversion Double to String
 Debug.Print s

 s = "<" & CStr(above) ' "<1,23" - explicit conversion with CStr
 Debug.Print s

 s = "<" & Str(above) ' "< 1.23" - explicit conversion with Str
 Debug.Print s

End Sub
```

But is your logic correct? `...CountIfs(rng, ">" & above, rng, "<=" & curr)` - greater than above sounds strange ;-)