# VBA CountIfs with variable decimal argument returns zero

Tags: excel, for-loop, countif, vba

I am trying to write a code which searches through a range `C1:C88211` and counts the occurences of finding a value between `i` and `m` using `countifs`. Al the values lie between 1 and 3 and I want to count in steps of 0.05 using a for loop which adds 0.05 to the criteria on every new run. I have made a macro for this which functions properly with steps of 1, but not with decimal steps.

```
 Dim i As Single
Dim m As Single
Dim k As Long
Dim rws As Long
Dim rng As Range
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("blad4").Activate

rws = Cells(Worksheets("blad4").rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("blad4").Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(rws, 3))

k = 1
For i = 0 To 3 Step 1
    m = i + 1
    Cells(k, 6) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng, ">=" & i, rng, "<" & m)
    Cells(k, 7) = i
    Cells(k, 8) = m
k = k + 1

Next i
```

When the above is run the follwing is placed on the worksheet:

```
75168   0.00    1.00
6131    1.00    2.00
1681    2.00    3.00
```

75168 datapoints between 0 and 1,
6131 between 1 and 2 etcetera...

However, when the stepsize is changed to anything containing decimals like shown below it returns only zeros.

```
k = 1
For i = 0 To 2 Step 0.05
    m = i + 0.05
    Cells(k, 6) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng, ">=" & i, rng, "<" & m)
    Cells(k, 7) = i
    Cells(k, 8) = m
k = k + 1
```

I think it might have something to do with either the type of the variable, single, I am using or simply the wrong formatting, missing brackets etc..

Help would be much appreciated.

Both the data and the excel version have a "." as decimal seperator, so i don't think that s the problem. (Although the system uses a comma as decimal seperator)

UPDATE--------------------------------------------------------------------------

The code is probably correct, so i've looked at my worksheet a bit more and tried a few changes. First of, this is what the result should look like for the first 5 rows. I obtained this result without using VBA, (with the amount of graphs I need to generate this is not an option though.)

```
0     0.05  32487
0.05  0.1   6662
0.1   0.15  5276
0.15  0.2   4854
0.2   0.25  3886
```

In excel options/advanced, the box "use system seperators is unchecked and as decimal seperator a "." is used and as thousands seperator a "," is used.

Now for the fun part. When I select my range of data, and replaced all the "." with commas. When I run the code now, This is the result:

```
0     0.05  0
0.05  0.1   111
0.1   0.15  108
0.15  0.2   39
0.2   0.25  38
```

Clearly, this is not correct, it does however return values and not zeroes.
When I change my settings to make "," the decimal seperator I still get the values displayed above.

I tried multiple different combinations of system seperators and also tried the fix found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737018/countifs-not-working-with-decimals) using `Str` or `Cstr`, but it always returns either zeroes or the values displayed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't succeed in getting countifs to work properly. I feel this is caused by de different use of decimal seperators in my excel, vba and on my os, i've encountered more problems with this.

In the end i used frequency to accomplish the same thing. `FrRange` is the range containing the data. `BnRange` is a range containing the bins form 0 to 3 in steps of 0.05

```
Set FrRange = Ws4.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(rws, 2))
Set BnRange = Ws4.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Lastbin, 1))
Range(Cells(k, 3), Cells(Lastbin, 3)).FormulaArray = WorksheetFunction_
    .frequency(FrRange, BnRange)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and for me it worked; however I had altered it slightly...
I added a range reference within the code.

```
Sub TestForStepDecimal()

    Dim i As Single
    Dim m As Single
    Dim k As Long: k = 20
    Dim SrcRange As Range: Set SrcRange = Range("$F13:$M13")

    For i = 0 To 2 Step 0.25
        m = i + 0.25
        Cells(k, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(SrcRange, ">=" & i, SrcRange, "<" & m)
        Cells(k, 2) = i
        Cells(k, 3) = m
    k = k + 1

    Next i

End Sub
```

As a result; I don't think there is anything wrong with that portion of the code; so with a closer look I then noticed you have a typo.

```
Dim rows As Long
```

However 'rws' is then referenced in the range and calculations not 'rows' - it's probably something to do with this.

**** **UPDATE** ****

Taking your newer code - I have made some further minor changes...
When I ran the code - I noticed using type Single gave some rounding errors - these have been updated to type Double.

The following works for me...

```
Sub TestForStepDecimal2()
    Dim i As Double
    Dim m As Double
    Dim k As Long: k = 1
    Dim rws As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("blad4")
        rws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(rws, 3))

        For i = 0 To 2 Step 0.05
            m = i + 0.05
            .Cells(k, 6) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng, ">=" & i, rng, "<" & m)
            .Cells(k, 7) = i
            .Cells(k, 8) = m
            k = k + 1
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I followed your advise and cleaned my code up a bit. However I still can't get it to work with a stepsize with decimals and with stepsize 1 it works so it didnt have anything to do with the typo I think.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the updated code in my first message.

Comment: Updated code added to answer. If it still doesn't work - I would presume to say it is the worksheet itself which may contain errors/formatting issues.

Comment: Thank you for at least ruling out that my code is faulty. I've looked at the worksheet and tried a few things which i will describe in my question. Maybe you could have a look at it?